# Adjusting predicted values based on average offsets from past predictions

Tags: statistics, predictive-modeling, descriptive-statistics

This question is more about inference and decision making based on statistical data, so I hope I'm in the right place. If not, let me know if I should migrate this question elsewhere.

I have a data set specifying the predicted shoe size of different people for various shoe models, and also the manually measured correct shoe size.

For instance person #1 was predicted to have a shoe size of 8 for shoe model A, and the actual size she wears is 8.5. Each record includes the person, shoe model, predicted size and actual size. I already calculated the delta between these two values for each record, then summarized the average offset and standard deviation for all shoe models. Here's an example of the offset data (*n* is the sample size from the average offset and standard deviation was calculated for each model):

```
+-------+----------------+-----+----+
| model | Average Offset | SD  | n  |
+-------+----------------+-----+----+
|     1 | 0.4            | 1.0 | 16 |
|     2 | -0.8           | 0.8 |  5 |
|     3 | 0.8            | 0.7 | 10 |
|     4 | 0.5            | 0.9 | 12 |
|     5 | 0.7            | 0.8 |  6 |
|     6 | 0.1            | 0.9 | 28 |
|     7 | 0.5            | 0.8 | 16 |
|     8 | 0.1            | 0.7 | 18 |
|     9 | 0.3            | 0.5 |  6 |
|    10 | 2.7            | 0.3 |  5 |
|    11 | -0.2           | 0.6 | 33 |
|    12 | 1.0            | 0.5 |  6 |
|    13 | 0.0            | 0.0 |  5 |
|    14 | -0.1           | 0.6 | 13 |
|    15 | 0.0            | 0.4 |  4 |
|    16 | -0.9           | 0.5 |  7 |
|    17 | 0.2            | 0.8 |  9 |
|    18 | -0.2           | 0.8 | 20 |
|    19 | -1.1           | 0.7 |  9 |
|    20 | -0.1           | 0.6 | 14 |
|    21 | -1.1           | 0.8 | 55 |
|    22 | -1.2           | 0.8 | 12 |
|    23 | -0.3           | 0.5 | 12 |
|    24 | -0.1           | 0.4 | 10 |
|    25 | 0.6            | 0.9 | 29 |
+-------+----------------+-----+----+
```

And as a chart:
[image]

If you're wondering why analyze this per shoe model at all, then the answer is that we know from shop experience that different shoe models have particular structures and materials that have of consistent effect on shoe size preference.

Now to my actual question:
My goal is to plug average offsets back into the prediction calculation to adjust it based on previously recorded offsets.

The question is - when does it make sense to use an offset value, and when that value is unusable.

I tend to disregard average offsets where the SD is close to the size of the average, but mathematically, plugging in such an average to adjust all predictions for this model is likely to do more good than harm. Or does it?

What would be a good approach to decide which of these averages is useful?

Suggestion for additional insights or analysis techniques are welcome.

Comment: What you describe sounds like the "boosting" model ensembling technique where you repeatedly take a model and improve it by training another model on the previous model's errors. You could take your initial model, train a simple regression tree on the initial model's errors, add the results of both models together and repeat. Figure out the best number of iterations using a validation set (or cross validation). This might result in better predictions than you have right now.

Comment: Thanks @stmax, that will definitely help when this is part of a machine learning algorithm. Currently, though, it isn't, as the data set is still fairly small and my question is probably a more basic statistical inference question.